# How to check Xmlhttprequest , jsonp is supported at server side or not

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I want to read data from x ml web API , I have the URL from which data is coming in x ml format directly and I want to map this data into my own created Html page. After Goggling I come to know that xmlhttprequest is the only way to read data from web API, now how come I know whether the xmlhttprequest is supported at the server side? as i have only the URL and How I can check same. Is there any need to add JSONP at server side if I want to read X ml URL?

Following is the URL:

http://www.rbsk.nrhmharyana.gov.in/api/GIS?year=2014